# Is there a better way to loop though this XML list

Tags: php, xml, loops, simplexml

Here's the loop

```
 function List($input) 
{   //I'm sure there's a better way of doing this... 
    $list =  simplexml_load_string($input);
    foreach($list->nation as $nation){
        foreach($nation->region as $region){
            $temp['url']=  (string)$region['url']; 
            $temp['name'] = (string)$region['name']; 
            $temp['nation'] = (string)$nation['name'];
            $out['regions'][] = $temp;              
        }
        $temp['url'] = (string)$nation['url'];
        $temp['name'] = (string)$nation['name'];
        unset($temp['nation']);  
        $out['nations'][] = $temp;
    }
    return $out;        
}
```

Sample Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<regions>
  <nation url="canada" name="Canada" >
    <region url="abbotsford" name="Abbotsford" />
    <region url="barrie" name="Barrie" />
    <region url="brantford" name="Brantford" />
    <region url="calgary" name="Calgary" />
    <region url="charlottetown" name="Charlottetown" />
 </nation>
 <nation url="ireland" name="Ireland">
    <region url="cork" name="Cork"/>
    <region url="dublin" name="Dublin"/>
    <region url="galway" name="Galway"/>
    <region url="limerick" name="Limerick"/>
    <region url="waterford" name="Waterford"/>
 </nation>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: "Better" in what respect? Maybe try http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: more efficient and/or cleaner code.  I'm not happy with the requirement of the unset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function List($input) {
    $list = simplexml_load_string($input);

    // guarantee fixed output format
    $out = array('regions' => array(), 'nations' => array());

    foreach ($list->nation as $nation){
        foreach ($nation->region as $region){
            $out['regions'][] = array(
                'url'    => $region['url'],
                'name'   => $region['name'],
                'nation' => $nation['name']
            );
        }

        $out['nations'][] = array(
            'url'  => $nation['url'],
            'name' => $nation['name']
        );
    }

    return $out;        
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of it that way!  I added (string) to the output so that it was not an simple xml object anymore..  but your code works perfectly other than that!  And is clean!